# Query for Joining 2 tables and create a new column based on the output

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Can someone help me with this. I'm using SQL-Developer.

say this is my query

```
select
ac.customer_name, 
acra.receipt_number,
acra.receipt_amount amount_value,
rcta.trx_number,
rcta.attribute5 as office_code
from
ar_customers ac,
ar_cash_receipts_all acra,
ra_customer_trx_all rcta
where
ac.customer_id=acra.customer_id and
acra.cash_receipt_id = rcta.cash_receipt_id and
acra.receipt_amount > 5000;
```

to this output i want to add a column stamp_value which should contain value 1 .
how to do it?

Comment: I have tagged this question Oracle because of your mention of SQL Developer. If this is incorrect please tag it with the correct RDBMS (MySQL, SQL Server etc).

Comment: select
ac.customer_name, 
acra.receipt_number,
acra.receipt_amount amount_value,
rcta.trx_number,
rcta.attribute5 as office_code
from
ar_customers ac,
ar_cash_receipts_all acra,
ra_customer_trx_all rcta
where
ac.customer_id=acra.customer_id and
acra.cash_receipt_id = rcta.cash_receipt_id and
acra.receipt_amount > 5000;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN amount_value > 5000 THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
       END stamp_value
  FROM t1 JOIN t2 ...
```

Comment: i posted a query .can u show me how to change this query to get my desired ouput.Thanks in advance